# Spring Batch IllegalArgumentException while executing step with chunk after step with tasklet

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

I have scenario where first step is xml schema validation, I have used tasklet to validate the xml against schema using ref="beanId", note that no chunk is processed here. The next step is with chunk, i.e. reader, processor and writer configuration. I'm getting IllegalArgument exception if I execute schema validation tasklet and on next . The "nextStep" is with chunk. The exception is Step [nextStep] has both a  element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet. The 'nextStep' defination have chunk but not ref element. Complete code is below.

Case 1 - If job is executed with below configuration its works fine, but I need to processe data in xml after schema validation. Case 2 is falure scenario. Not sure whats going wrong. Is it not valid in spring batch to execuet step with chuck after tasklet only step?

```
<batch:job id="DataEnhancement" job-repository="jobRepository">
        <!-- 1. Validate Input file against schema, if validation fails, notify 
            error -->
        <batch:step id="validateSchema">
            <tasklet ref="SchemaValidatorTasklet" transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
            <batch:end on="*" />
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="generateErrorResponseXml" />
        </batch:step>

        <!-- 9. Generate response xml for schema validation failure.  -->
        <batch:step id="generateErrorResponseXml" parent="validateSchema">
            <tasklet ref="schemaValidationErrorXmlTasklet"
                allow-start-if-complete="true" />
            <batch:next on="*" to="notifyError" />
        </batch:step>

        <!-- 10. Error notification tasklet to notify error. TODO : No requirements 
            on error notifications -->
        <batch:step id="notifyError">
            <tasklet ref="notifyFailureTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
            <batch:fail on="*" exit-code="FAILED" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

Case 2 - I have added readHeader step after validateSchema step, modified configuration is as below.
    <batch:job id="DataEnhancement" job-repository="jobRepository">
        <!-- 1. Validate Input file against schema, if validation fails, notify 
            error -->
        <batch:step id="validateSchema">
            <tasklet ref="SchemaValidatorTasklet" transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
            <!-- <batch:end on="*" /> -->
            <batch:next on="*" to="readHeader" />
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="generateErrorResponseXml" />
        </batch:step>

        <!-- 2. Read PDE header details and persist into stage tables -->
        <batch:step id="readHeader" parent="validateSchema">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlHeaderReader" processor="HeaderProcessor"
                    writer="hibernateItemWriter" commit-interval="1" />
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:end on="*" />
            <!-- <batch:next on="*" to="readPdeTrailer" /> -->
            <batch:next on="FAILED" to="notifyError" />
        </batch:step>

        <!-- 9. Generate response xml for schema validation failure. -->
        <batch:step id="generateErrorResponseXml" parent="validateSchema">
            <tasklet ref="schemaValidationErrorXmlTasklet"
                allow-start-if-complete="true" />
            <batch:next on="*" to="notifyError" />
        </batch:step>

        <!-- 10. Error notification tasklet to notify error. TODO : No requirements 
            on error notifications -->
        <batch:step id="notifyError">
            <tasklet ref="notifyFailureTasklet" allow-start-if-complete="true" />
            <batch:fail on="*" exit-code="FAILED" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
```

Getting following stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DataEnhancement': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#47634763' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'flow'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47634763': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#27b627b6' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#27b627b6': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7d267d26' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7d267d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'readHeader' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.batch.app.XmlReadHibernateWriteBatchApplication.main(XmlReadHibernateWriteBatchApplication.java:36)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47634763': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#27b627b6' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#27b627b6': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7d267d26' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7d267d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'readHeader' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#27b627b6': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7d267d26' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7d267d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'readHeader' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7d267d26': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'readHeader' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a <chunk/> element and a 'ref' attribute  referencing a Tasklet.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:89)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.StepParserStepFactoryBean.getObject(StepParserStepFactoryBean.java:268)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.StepParserStepFactoryBean.getObject(StepParserStepFactoryBean.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: I tried with the JobExecutionDecider, but problem results into same problem. It seems something is wrong with configuration, however, I'm not able to find the issue. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reading" your (unformatted) stacktrace the problem is here:

> Error creating bean with name 'readHeader': FactoryBean threw
>   exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Step [readHeader] has both a
>   element and a 'ref' attribute referencing a Tasklet

and the problem is here:

`<batch:step id="readHeader" parent="validateSchema">`

you are inherit step config from `validateSchema` step which holds a ref to a tasket and `readHeader` is implementing a chunk-based step.
Remove `parent="validateSchema"` and all should works fine.

Comment: My apologies for unformatted stack trace, I tried formatting but couldn’t do it, and it’s lazy on my part that I didn’t put efforts research on how to format. Will do better next time :)
Being said that, thank you very much…solution worked…how can I miss this :)